# create XML document in python?

Tags: python, elementtree

When trying to import elementtree in Python 
I get this error can anyone help with that ?

I am getting no module:

```
ImportError: No module named elementtree.ElementTree
```

Answer (score 6):

The name of the module is [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), not `elementtree.ElementTree`.

```
>>> import xml.elementtree.ElementTree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named elementtree.ElementTree
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:
If you have cElementTree, why not use it? faster!

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```